# How to find propagation speed of wave eq. derived from Maxwell's eq?

Tags: electromagnetism, speed-of-light, maxwell-equations

In Heaviside-Lorentz unit($c=1$), solution of wave equation from Maxwell's eq "$\Box f=0$" is following.

$f \sim e^{i(wt\pm\vec{k}\vec{x})} $ $(s.t. w = k)$

I saw below process of finding propagation, but I don't understand the part of ⓐ

$\phi = wt \pm wx$($\because w = k$)

so, ⓐ $dx \over dt$$=1$

I thought "$\phi = wt \pm wx$($\because w = k$)"
should be ⓑ, not ⓐ

and I want to know why ⓑ is wrong and ⓐ is right.

### ⓑ

$\phi = wt \pm wx$

$\leftrightarrow \pm x = $$\phi - wt \over w$

$\leftrightarrow $$\pm $$dx \over dt $= $1 \over w$$d\phi \over dt$$-1$($\because \phi = \phi(x,t)$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phase velocity is defined as how the front of a constant phase is moving in space when time changes. Therefore, for $\phi(x,t) = \phi_o$, a constant. Under this condition:
$$
    v_p = \frac{dx}{dt}\vert_{\phi_0}.
$$

Therefore, in your ⓑ the
$$
  \frac{d\phi}{dt} = 0.
$$